# complete texture on obj model loaded

Tags: three.js

I am creating a texture using :
   `cImage="garden.jpg";
    var texture= new THREE.Texture(cImage);
    texture.needsUpdate=true;`

Now when I am trying to apply this on an object(a pyramid made in blender) loaded with objloader in three js,the image gets cropped and stretched in height,in other words,the image is not coming completely.It is not taking the complete image,although the width and height of image and object are identical.How can the complete image be put on the face of the object.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add UV coordinates in Blender before exporting.